# Can't load custom font in pdfbox in java app

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I want to use custom font. I places in resource folder and try to access. But i cant access that. I tried

```
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);
            String dir = "../resources/font/raleway/";
           PDType0Font font1BoldRaleway = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File(dir + "Raleway-Bold.ttf"));
```

Please suggest, where i should place those fonts and how to load it. I am getting font path is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

if the font is on classpath you can use it like this

`InputStream fontInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(trueTypeFont.getFile());
        return PDType0Font.load(doc, fontInputStream);`

where `File trueTypeFont = new File("font/raleway/Raleway-Bold.ttf");`

Comment: trueTypeFont.getFile() - this line give incompatible type. file cant be converted to java.lang.String.

Comment: how can i put font in classpath. I mean where i should put?